# Can i use my tools without rebuilding them after a debian upgrade?

Tags: debian, upgrade, c++

I am wondering if i have to recompile/rebuild my tools that i had built from sources previously, after an upgrade of Debian from Jessie to Stretsh.

My mains tools are:

- Omnet++ network simulator (based on Eclipse)
- Sumo trafic simulator
- Various programms written in Python
- Old versions of R (2-11)

I thaugth that my tools will be all broken, and consequently i need to rebuild them, but when i tried some of them (Omnet++, Sumo), seems that they worked fine, but i am not sure of their coherences,

So, if it works, is it possible that it works in inconsistent manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what libraries the tools use, and whether there are new versions of those in Stretch and whether the ABI of those new versions are backward compatible. That also means it might only be some functions in the programs that are broken.

I don't know your tools, but in general the safe approach is to recompile everything.

Comment: So, the safest approach is to recompile everything and by the way avoiding any inexpected behavior due to hazardous function behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Whether they will work depends on what do those tools depend on (can they locate stuff they depend on in new OS).

But since they remain on Debian based OS, they should continue working without any issues.

Comment: my tools depends on some C-librarys like Xerces and so on, anyway what is the safest approach ? trying to recompile all tools ?

Answer (score 0):

If a custom compiled program starts in the upgraded OS, that means it found the necessary dynamic libraries and should work fine in this respect. (It may still fail due to other incompatibilities, but recompilation wouldn't help that.) However, it might have found its dynamic libraries in obsolete packages, which aren't part of the new OS, but weren't automatically removed during the upgrade. So, if you later remove such an obsolete package (package management frontends usually highlight them in some way), your custom compiled program will break. (If you installed it via a custom package with a dependency on the now-obsolete library package, the package manager will warn, though.) You can discover dynamic library dependencies using the `ldd` tool, then find their corresponding packages using `dpkg -S`, and finally their status by `apt-cache policy`.

Prolonged use of obsolete packages is a security risk, because they do not receive security updates. Enabling the appropriate LTS repo usually helps with that for some time. Particularly, Xerces hasn't got a good reputation in this regard for its code quality.